# Animating a listview item when dataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have items in a listview that can get changed.
When a listview's items data is changed i want to animate that view to fade out and the new item to fade in.

Some help please?

Thanks

Comment: this is not what i am looking. the user presses a button and a item in the list gets switched with fad in/out between the new and old item.

Comment: @ilan please check the second answer of the above link.i think you can skip delete  just use animation part on Onclick event. here it is : Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                     GoTransitApp.this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right
                 );
anim.setDuration(500);
listView.getChildAt(index).startAnimation(anim );